# React-native :ReferenceError: TextInput is not defined

Tags: react-native

> I'm new to react-native so i don't know how to fix this error

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo- 
status-bar';
import React from 'react';     
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
 <TextInput  placeholder ="something"/> **The error is here**
 <StatusBar style="auto" />
</View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
```

I  have a trouble with Text input
and the image error is :[image]

How to fix this??

Answer (score 1):

You haven't imported the textinput

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';     
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,TextInput  } from 'react-native'; **import here**

export default function App() {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<Text>Hello World</Text>
<TextInput  placeholder ="something"/> **The error is here**
 <StatusBar style="auto" />
</View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
```

Use this code